pyarrow chunkedarray set at indices
Say I have
In [1]: import pyarrow as ap

In [2]: import pyarrow as pa

In [3]: ca = pa.chunked_array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])

In [4]: ca
Out[4]:
<pyarrow.lib.ChunkedArray object at 0x7f7afaaa4a90>
[
  [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  [
    4,
    5,
    6
  ]
]

I'd like to do something like
ca[[1, 4]] = [999, 888]

and end up with
<pyarrow.lib.ChunkedArray object at 0x7f7aef473d30>
[
  [
    1,
    999,
    3
  ],
  [
    4,
    888,
    6
  ]
]

I don't really mind if the result gets rechunked

PyArrow has the functionality to set values based on a mask (in fact replace values instead of set, given that the pyarrow Array is indeed immutable), but not with indices. However, you convert your indices to a mask, for now, and then use pyarrow.compute.replace_with_mask:
import numpy as np
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.compute as pc

ca = pa.chunked_array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
indices = [1, 4]

mask = np.zeros(len(ca), dtype=bool)
mask[indices] = True

pc.replace_with_mask(ca, mask, [999, 888])

gives
<pyarrow.lib.ChunkedArray object at 0x7fdfea44ddf0>
[
  [
    1,
    999,
    3
  ],
  [
    4,
    888,
    6
  ]
]

This assumes that the indices are sorted, though (see the comments for a workaround when that is not the case).
And see https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/25505 for a feature request to add a function to replace values directly based on indices.

Thanks - I tried this but it doesn't respect the order, e.g. if I use indices = [4, 1] I get the same result as if I use indices = [1, 4]

I think you'll have to sort values according to indices. values = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(indices, values))]


Arrow data is immutable, so values can be selected but not assigned.

https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/data.html#arrays
So you would have to do something like this:
ca2 = pa.chunked_array([ca[:1],[999], ca[2:]])

I'm fine with creating a copy, I need to have the new values set in those positions
